# Printing the current processes running on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, process, operating-system

I have used the following code to print the current running processes on Windows. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 
This code doesn't get the system processes. 
It only says "unknown" there. 
I have cross checked with Task Manager. Those process' names are printed in Task Manager. 
I have included 
`#pragma comment(lib, "Psapi.lib")` too. 
 
It is still not working. 

Any helps?

Comment: You don't have permission to see them. Just like you need to click "Show processes from all users" in Task Manager.

Comment: Nope. I have checked Task Manager. Those process names are printed in Task Manager.

Comment: You're probably building a 32-bit application on a 64-bit system, in which case you won't be able to retrieve information for any 64-bit processes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give admin privileges to your program to get this done.

Comment: I actually gave admin privileges. Still no use.